# Swift 2: Why is it necessary to apply ‘as!’ after getting new object by ‘copy()’?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I’ve created new SKEmitterNode object using copy() method. After that i’ve tried to write emitter.position but Xcode said «Ambiguous reference to member ‘position’». But, when i use type conversion «as! SKEmitterNode» after the «copy()», everything is ok. Can you explain me, please, why am i need to use «as!» in this case? I can’t understand this because when i check value type of «emit» variable in debugger, i can see that it’s already have the type SKEmitterNode, even without using «as! SKEmitterNode» after «copy()».

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let bangEmitter : SKEmitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle")!

    func makeBang(position: CGPoint) {

        // this method causes an error in second line
        // but, emit is already have type SKEmitterNode, as debugger says
        var emit = bangEmitter.copy()
        emit.position = position

        // this works ok
        var emit = bangEmitter.copy() as! SKEmitterNode
        emit.position = position

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `copy()` is a method defined by `NSObject` and is meant to be overriden by subclasses to provide their own implementation. `NSObject` itself doesn't support it and will throw an exception if you call `copy()` on it.

Since it's meant for subclassing, there's no way to tell what the class of the object that will be returned. In Objective-C, it returns an `id`; in Swift, this becomes `AnyObject`. Since you, the programmer, know what kind of object you are copying from, you can use `as! SomeClass` to tell the compiler what kind of object the copy is.

This also speaks to the difference between ObjectiveC and Swift. Objective-C is dynamic. In Objective-C, every time you *send a message*, the run time will check if the object responds to the message. This happens at **run time**. In Swift, you *call a method* and this happens at **compile time**. The compiler must know the object's type in order to call the right function / method.

This explains why you get `emit` as an `SKEmitterNode` in the debugger - this is run time. The compiler doesn't know that at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `as!` is an indicator that a check may fail.

> Swift 1.2 separates the notions of guaranteed conversion and forced conversion into two distinct operators. Guaranteed conversion is still performed with the as operator, but forced conversion now uses the as! operator. The ! is meant to indicate that the conversion may fail. This way, you know at a glance which conversions may cause the program to crash.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23

Answer (score 0):

Look up the definition of the function copy() and you'll see that it always returns `Any`, therefore you always need to cast it to the object that you're seeking.

Comment: Actually it returns `AnyObject`, not `Any`.